# Send message from a WebBrowser control to the parent application

Tags: c#, .net, http, webbrowser-control

I have two applications:

- A legacy one, written in .net
- A modern web application with cool html5/js features

I want to make them coexist so i'm considering integrating a [WebBrowser ActiveX control](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.7.2) in my .net application. I want to understand how "deep" i can make them communicate and more specifically:

**Which type of information can i send from the webapp to parent .net app?**

In Microsoft documentation, several events are associated to the `WebBrowser` class like [`Navigated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated?view=netframework-4.7.2) which seems to be triggered every time the webapp's url changes. So i can imagine a mechanism which:

- change the url
- without affecting the webapp content
- but passes some info to the .net app.
- example: navigating to http://my.web.app/#event=hello&content=you will tell me that event type `hello` was triggered with content `you`.

That sounds like a tedious process, so:

- Is there something higher level that this idea? At the beginning, i expected something like the [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) method?
- If not, is there a library that provides a higher level api to perform such things more easily?

Comment: CeFSharp (Chrome as a form/wpf control) would be something else to consider, it has nice async bindings for .Net classes - https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript & the other benefit of not being IE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can build a bridge between javascript code in modern application and your C# host application using this technique
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implement-two-way-com-between-dhtml-and-client

It allows to execute C# code from JS as well as invoke JS from C#. You need to set `ObjectForScripting` property of WebBrowser control to C# object, methods of which will be called and then invoke it like

```
window.external.YourCSharpObjectMethod('called from JS code');
```